# Fetching ALL facebook events from a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch **all** events from a single page to display them on our website. The problem, however, is that the API gives me only events that are created by the page itself and no events that have been added to the page. So when browsing the events at facebook, the user sees events that are not listed on our website.

Right now, I'm requesting the events with my personal user token that has `manage_pages` for the specific page. When using a page access token obtained by the Graph API Explorer I get even less events.

I'm using this endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/<Page>/events`

Comment: please include the relevant api calls and code

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/events: _“Only Events for which the requesting User is listed as a Host or Guest will be returned.”_ Don’t think there is a way to get anything else right now.

Comment: @luschn I have added the endpoint that I'm requesting.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I know that too, that's why I'm asking because this restriction makes the whole endpoint pointless (or I'm doing it wrong). Thank you anyway for your reply.